# How to add documents related to a table named vehicule to a different table

Tags: php, laravel

The code that stores the image and creates a new vehicule, my boss asks me to add a file input for many documents such as pdf and mp4 extensions, but he wants that file to be stored in another table!
Here's my code (I didn't write any code for documents yet!)

```
public function store(VehiculeStoreRequest $request)
        {
            //getting validated fields
            $validated = $request->validated();
            //uploading vehicule image
            $file = $validated["image"];
            $filename = uniqid() . '.' . File::extension($file->getClientOriginalName());
            $path = "public/";
            Storage::disk('local')->put($path . $filename, file_get_contents($file));
            $validated['image'] = $filename;
            $validated['disponibilite'] = true;
            Vehicule::create($validated);
        }
```

here's the code of the new table :

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('document_vehicules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->foreignId('vehicule_id')->references('id')->on('vehicules')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->boolean('isvalid');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: inserting and updating related models https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Answer (score 0):

Create a `VehiculeFile` Model. Define one-to-one or one-to-many relationship in `Vehicule` model

```
class Vehicule extends Model
{

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VehiculeFile::class);
    }
}
```

Then in your store method

```
public function store(VehiculeStoreRequest $request)
        {
            //getting validated fields
            $validated = $request->validated();
            //uploading vehicule image
            $file = $validated["image"];
            $filename = uniqid() . '.' . File::extension($file->getClientOriginalName());
            $path = "public/";
            Storage::disk('local')->put($path . $filename, file_get_contents($file));
            $validated['image'] = $filename;
            $validated['disponibilite'] = true;
            $data=Vehicule::create($validated);
            $data->files->create($path . $filename);
        }
```

Migration for VehiculeFile might look like this

```
    public function up()
        {
        Schema::create('document_vehicules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('path');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
}
```